# Wordpress Custom Function in Plugin to Return Post ID from Specified Category

Tags: php, wordpress

Hoping you can help me figure out why I can't get **get_first_post_in_category** to successfully return a usable post ID. At the moment I am using the [Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.me/) to create a plugin that removes the first post of a specified category (through the admin options page) from the primary loop. All is well until I try and programmatically retrieve the post ID.

Here I define my hook (works fine):

```
// In private function define_public_hooks()
$this->loader->add_action( 'pre_get_posts', $plugin_public, 'exclude_featured_post_pre_injection');
```

Here is the callback function I am using to exclude a specific post from the main query. If $first_post_in_category_id is manually set, it works perfectly. If I try and set it to " = get_first_post_in_category();" I am thrown a 500 error.

```
public function exclude_featured_post_pre_injection($query){

    // Doesn't work
    $first_post_in_category_id = $this->get_first_post_in_category();

    //Works
    // $first_post_in_category_id = '427';

    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array($first_post_in_category_id));
    }
}
```

And here is the issue ::: this function I am attempting to just return the ID of the first post in the category to be used in other action/filter callbacks. If I call this, it returns a 500 error.

```
public function get_first_post_in_category(){

    $cat_id = get_option('sticky_content_category_id');
    // currently returns (string) '3' which has posts in it

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'cat' => $cat_id
    );

    $latest_cat_post = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();

    $first_post_id = the_ID();

  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

  return $first_post_id;
}
```

Any idea on the best way to resolve the issues I am running into?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see how it can cause an error 500 but the code below works for me.

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Wordpress');

//echo $category_id;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
    echo the_ID();
endwhile;
```